# How to use 'border' instead of 'border-right' to specify a detailed right border style?

Tags: html, css, border

I find that I have to use the following style to specify a style for my right border:

```
border-right: 1px solid black;
```

When I tried to incorporate this information into my border element like this, it didn't work:

```
border: 0 1px solid black 0 0;
```

Assuming my syntax is wrong, is there a way to specify the right border style using only the border element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Border sets all of them.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

You'll need to use one that's specific to your need.

Answer (score 3):

No, for different borders you have to use border-right and so on, but can specify all of them then override:

```
border: 0px;
border-right: ...
```